# Is it possible to disable AMP Email on mobile devices?

Tags: email, mime-types, mime, amp-email

As a developer, is it possible to disable AMP Email on mobile devices so that the `text/html`, MIME content-type would display instead?

Answer (score 2):

No. You can, however, hide AMP elements and replace them by something non-AMP using media-queries and good old `display:none` (and probably some additional cross-email-client-compatible nonsense), but I am not sure if that is what one actually needs, unless you target `mso` obv. as then everything is allowed to me.

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming that there is no way to do this and sharing a good alternative solution that would work for our needs. Going to share this information with my team to see how we will want to proceed.

Comment: The answer is roye7777777 good. Don't forget about the 100KB limit on the AMP part. This restriction may prevent you from making two versions of the same email, especially if the AMP is a complex email. Read more here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail/testing-dynamic-email.